# Annotating a corpus for SMS Text Normalization

Tags: nlp, corpus

I want to build an SMS Text Normalizer using Supervised Learning Techniques. SMS Text Normalization is the task of converting SMS lingo into correct English.

eg) 'wts up? r u hme?' will become 'What's up? Are you home?'.

Ideally, I would like a readily available corpus with SMS Text and the subsequent English text as the training data. However, I couldn't find any such publicly available data set online. (SMS Text corpora are available, but not the corresponding text in grammatically correct English) People who have worked on similar problems before seem to have manually annotated the text.

1. Which would be the quickest way to annotate this text? Possibly, one can scrape data for each word token from standard SMS conversion sites/ urban dictionary to get the equivalent English words. But this would work correctly only for standard SMS Text and only marginally reduce the manual work.
2. Partition the corpus and ask individuals to annotate it manually, but this will be very slow especially for large amount of text.

Answer (score 0):

Building an annotated corpus requires a lot of effort (see related work in [this paper](http://www.academia.edu/11455663/QUICK_PAD_TAGGER_AN_EFFICIENT_GRAPHICAL_USER_INTERFACE_FOR_BUILDING_ANNOTATED_CORPORA_WITH_MULTIPLE_ANNOTATION_LAYERS)). You have now to choices:

- You can do all annotations from scratch. (takes long and error-prone)
- You can use a tool (e.g. a lemmatizer) which generates annotations and you can correct them. (quicker way)

For us, the use of a custom annotation tool worked out (see link of the paper). This tool combined both solutions and speeds up the annotation process.